# Add a list in another list

Tags: python, list

Am adding a list inside another list in python.

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'aa']
a.insert(3, ['b','a'])
print a
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, ['b', 'a'], 'a', 'aa']
```

Desired output:

```
[1, 2, 3,'b', 'a', 'a', 'aa']
```

I want the output to be a single list and not a hierarchy of lists. What should I do in such a case?

---

Follow-up question

```
    total = []
    tname = temp_list[0]
    if (tname == 'order'):
      total[0:0] = temp_list
    else:
      total[10:10] = temp_list
```

Input is a json (copying a subset):

```
["order", "7", "39136", "O", "252004.18", "1996-01-10", "2-HIGH", "Clerk#000000470", "0", "ly special requests "]
["order", "32", "130057", "O", "208660.75", "1995-07-16", "2-HIGH", "Clerk#000000616", "0", "ise blithely bold, regular requests. quickly unusual dep"]
["line_item", "1", "155190", "7706", "1", "17", "21168.23", "0.04", "0.02", "N", "O", "1996-03-13", "1996-02-12", "1996-03-22", "DELIVER IN PERSON", "TRUCK", "egular courts above the"]
["line_item", "1", "67310", "7311", "2", "36", "45983.16", "0.09", "0.06", "N", "O", "1996-04-12", "1996-02-28", "1996-04-20", "TAKE BACK RETURN", "MAIL", "ly final dependencies: slyly bold "]
```

Output (subset):

```
[["order", "7", "39136", "O", "252004.18", "1996-01-10", "2-HIGH", "Clerk#000000470", "0", "ly special requests "], ["line_item", "7", "182052", "9607", "1", "12", "13608.60", "0.07", "0.03", "N", "O", "1996-05-07", "1996-03-13", "1996-06-03", "TAKE BACK RETURN", "FOB", "ss pinto beans wake against th"], ["line_item", "7", "145243", "7758", "2", "9", "11594.16", "0.08", "0.08", "N", "O", "1996-02-01", "1996-03-02", "1996-02-19", "TAKE BACK RETURN", "SHIP", "es. instructions"], ["line_item", "7", "94780", "9799", "3", "46", "81639.88", "0.10", "0.07", "N", "O", "1996-01-15", "1996-03-27", "1996-02-03", "COLLECT COD", "MAIL", " unusual reques"], ["line_item", "7", "163073", "3074", "4", "28", "31809.96", "0.03", "0.04", "N", "O", "1996-03-21", "1996-04-08", "1996-04-20", "NONE", "FOB", ". slyly special requests haggl"], ["line_item", "7", "151894", "9440", "5", "38", "73943.82", "0.08", "0.01", "N", "O", "1996-02-11", "1996-02-24", "1996-02-18", "DELIVER IN PERSON", "TRUCK", "ns haggle carefully ironic deposits. bl"], ["line_item", "7", "79251", "1759", "6", "35", "43058.75", "0.06", "0.03", "N", "O", "1996-01-16", "1996-02-23", "1996-01-22", "TAKE BACK RETURN", "FOB", "jole. excuses wake carefully alongside of "], ["line_item", "7", "157238", "2269", "7", "5", "6476.15", "0.04", "0.02", "N", "O", "1996-02-10", "1996-03-26", "1996-02-13", "NONE", "FOB", "ithely regula"]]
```

This gives me multiple lists inside a parent list, rather than the expected output of a single list. Any idea as to what is the cause?

Comment: please show input and output

Comment: This is no problem with my solution, also you haven't showed how you iterate through the input so it's unclear how you've reached this problem

Comment: @jamylak I think I see my mistake, thanks for clearing this part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'aa']
>>> a[3:3] = ['b','a']
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 'b', 'a', 'a', 'aa']
```